# Can I easily add a drain for my basement laundry?

Tags: plumbing, basement, washer

We just bought a house. The basement has a receptacle for an electric dryer, and taps for hot and cold water, but no drain for a washer. Would this be an easy fix? Don't know why they would have hot and cold faucet but nowhere for the water to go?

[image: Photo #26]

Comment: Could you post a picture of the basement?   No seriously... that space is so finished it doesn't even look like a basement.  I can't believe any builder would fit a washer-dryer stand without a drain.  It's impossible without a drain, and drains are super hard to install.  I kinda get the impression this was a rough basement, and the last guy told their drywaller "make this space pretty for resale" and the drywaller covered everything ugly.  Normally when a space is properly finished, there's a little recessed box with both valves and a drain, that's not present here.

Comment: Washer/dryers take **6** connections:  Drain, cold, hot*, dryer vent*, 120V*, and EITHER 240V or gas.  Hot is not needed for heating washers, dryer vent is not needed for condensing dryers, 120V is not needed for washer-dryer pairs made to run all on 240.

Comment: lol. oh my. well this house is in pristine condition according to the home inspection. i just cant seem to add up the pieces. faucets. outlet. but no drain? maybe it was a sink but even then? im so confused. so youre saying it might be behind the wall or something?

Comment: The question is too broad for our format with the limited information we have, and I've voted to close. I suggest you contact the seller/realtor and politely ask for any information they're willing to share. With faucets and a finished dryer connection I'd be a bit surprised if there isn't a hidden drain stack as well.

Comment: @Ally I think your best hope is it's behind the wall.  Try to figure out a reason they would cover it up?   If it is simply absent, and the house was sold as "with W/D hookups", that's fraud -- the drain is the most fundamental part of "hookups" and hardest to retrofit.  Other hookups can be avoided with clever appliance choices, not that one.  I'd be aiming for litigation, relief from the insurer, etc.

Comment: I would also bet on behind the wall (or possibly above the ceiling) and covered with drywall "to make pretty for sale." Or if you see a lot of damage to the landscaping outside that wall, they were running it straight out onto the ground though the wall, which is not exactly to plumbing code, as they say, and that hole has been covered up by the new drywall. Not hiding in the closet to the left? While out there, do look for signs of the dryer vent, as well.

Comment: Is the hookup under a bathroom or kitchen sink? Perhaps you can determine where that there is a drain coming down the wall from a hookup upstairs. That will be an easy place to tap in to.

Comment: Hey guy I paid to inspect my house before I bought it who said it was "pristine" - how did you miss this blatant flaw, and send my refund for your alleged "services" by the end of the week, please!

Comment: THANKS guys so much. REALLY helpful. and will look into this and reach out to the home inspector. was it his job to note this? or find the drain as well? thanks guys.

Comment: Not his job to **find** it. **Definitely** his job to **note** the lack of a drain and a dryer vent (while the dryer vent may not be required for a certain type of dryer, your inspector should certainly have noted that there was no vent, and the drain is non-optional.) The (apparent, unless it's where we cannot see it) lack of a 120V outlet is also a likely problem for this hookup.

Comment: consider that the location may have been moved with a long hose run to the original drain location and vent. ( ie. look everywhere around for the drain. ).   Can you find the vent on the outside of the house?